# Excel Count to next number in cell when document is opened

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to make an Excel document that will count to the next number in a cell every time the document is opened.  Is there a way?  I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Could you please add more detail to your question, perhaps by providing an example of how you would like this to work? As is, it seems you want a cell to be augmented (+1) every time the workbook is opened, but it's not entirely clear this is what you are asking. A little more detail will help you get answers.

Answer (score 1):

You need an event which will trigger the count up process. This is only doable with VBA as far as I know. But thats not difficult.

1. Open Excel and the VBA editor with ALT+F11
2. Place this code under *ThisWorkbook*

   ```
   Private Sub Workbook_Open()
       Sheets(1).[A1] = Sheets(1).[A1] + 1
   End Sub
   ```

Each time your Workbook will be opened, it counts up a counter in cell A1 in the first sheet.

---

Just for the geeks. Its even possible to hide the counter inside your VBA code. 
Place this code in *ThisWorkbook* and see what happens if you reopen your workbook.

```
Const counter = 1

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    countUP = Mid(ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(1).CodeModule.Lines(1, 1), 17) + 1
    Application.VBE.CodePanes(1).CodeModule.ReplaceLine 1, "Const counter = " & countUP
End Sub
```

Comment: You'll need to specify the sheet if there's more than one sheet in the workbook. (There's no guarantee the workbook will always be saved with the same sheet active.)